# Rails Engines 3.2 in older app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

This might be an incredibly simple question, but I'm writing my first Rails engine (Rails 3.2) and this is all pretty new.

My engine is meant to Email Delivery (do the sending and the logging of messages) for a few of my older Rails apps (3.0.11, 2.3.15, 2.3.14).  I thought I would be able to just create this application and mount it to the older apps.

Simply put, must I upgrade the older apps before being able to use an engine written in a new version?

Answer (score 0):

I went on #rubyonrails on irc and got a bit more information.

"You should be able to use new engines in older apps as long as you don't use any APIs not in the new version you'll be fine."

and

If the engine requires a different gem version than your application does: "You'll have to resolve those issues manually"

That should get me started....